# How do I expand my /home partion?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I accidentally left 1tb of unallocated space, and decided to expand my /home partition(sda6) but somehow I cannot, tried all different "answers" here but none of them worked, so I have to ask directly..

I have Windows 10 + Ubuntu 17.10 dual-boot solution, with Ubuntu booting first at boot(selecting OS in GRUB), and using Gparted from Ubuntu ISO(set up via Unetbootin in Win 10).

Here I post also image if partitions - sorry for phone picture..

EDIT: I installed it using one big guide out there, if i recall correctly - sda1 is default partition which PC shipped with, should do something with Windows i believe, sda2 is Windows C: drive, sda3 is well..swap, sda5 is / (root fs), sda6 is /home, sda7/8/9 is /boot, /var and /tmp in this order. Hope that helps, Also updated screenshot now with mount points.
PS: Sorry for language

[image: New GParted Screenshot]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74722/discussion-on-question-by-benjamin-forro-how-do-i-expand-my-home-partion).

Answer (score 2):

Since your linux "partitions' are actually logical drives in the extended partition, you have to add the free space to the extended partition before you can expand any of your linux drives.

After, adding the free space to the extended partition. Move the logical drives  until the space is next to the one that you want to expand. You may need to move them one at a time, and they should be unmounted in order to move them.

Note: moving the root drive ( / ) can cause boot problems.

EDIT:

In comment you say that sda7 is /boot. This folder contains grub's files. Moving it may cause grub to crash as it will not be able to find the location of it's boot files (grub finds boot files by physical address before drives are mounted). You should reinstall grub after moving /boot. If you can not unmount /boot, you have to boot a liveCD to move it; which complictes reinstalling grub.

Comment: I read the picture so that the free space is already part of the extended partition.

Comment: @PerlDuck -- it maybe, it is a little hard to be for sure. oh never mind, the graphic at the top show that it is.

Comment: The unpartitioned space is already a part of the logical partition, the little light blue rectangle extends all the way around it in the picture.

Comment: @Panther -- yes I just noticed that. though the second part of my answer is valid as his /home may be sd6

Comment: Just saying. Sometimes you need to move partitions one at a time also.  Just update the answer if there are problems

Comment: I dont really understand but, if I move /boot to its original order, then I will still have to reinstall Grub? If yes, How?